# Spring boot, Render static page

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

this is my security config:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/newuser").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

First of all i'm redirected to login page when i'm not authenticated.
Second when i'm trying to create a new user requesting this path "/newuser" Response status is ok but the page isn't displayed .
These are my Controller methods:

```java
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "loginpage.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/newuser")
public String newUser() {
    return "signup.html";
}
```

This is my loginpage.html

```
  <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Title</title>

         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AuthenticationController">
        <form role="form" ng-submit="signin()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="credentials.username"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password"
                    class="form-control" id="password" name="password" ng-model="credentials.password"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <a href ng-click="newuser()">Create new account</a>
    </div>


    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            code.application.initialize(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['authentication']);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error while initializing Application Content Developer:", error);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/AuthenticationController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my signup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p>SIGNUP</p>

    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            code.application.initialize(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['authentication']);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error while initializing Application Content Developer:", error);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/AuthenticationController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my project main structure:

[image]

The thing i cannot understand is : Why login page is rendered successfully but signup page is ignored and not rendered at all.

Comment: Is your `newUser()` method being hit?

Comment: yes, it returns the page , the status is 200, but it doesn't render it , view remains the same loginpage.html

Comment: Can you provide some more information on this, like folder structure, the whole controller and the pom.xml?

Comment: @eXpas in your previous comment you state "view remains the same loginpage.html". Could you clarify that a bit? Are you getting redirected from `/newuser` to `/login` or do you remain on `/newuser` but see an empty page, an error page, etc.?

Comment: Provide more information about your project structure, signup.html view and etc.

Comment: @sthzg well first time i'm redirected to `/login` when i am not authenticated, then when i press create button , i'm expecting to be redirected to `/newuser` and a render of signup page, but URI points to the same `/login` path. On network console i see that response is OK and the signup page is returned , but how to render it,  what i am missing ?

Comment: This looks like angular issue to me, can you show the javascript for <a href ng-click="newuser()">Create new account</a>

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to try a default success url. Eg:

```
.loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/newuser", true)
```